# Replace MySql database root image links with subdomain folders?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Im trying to figure out a way to update some of my images in my database which are pointing to the wrong place. It was easy to do with the images which were in the wrong subfolder as I could just use a simple plugin to search for http://url.com/sub1/folder/ and change to http://url.com/sub2/folder/

But these are in root, so http://url.com/image.jpg and need to be http://url.com/sub2/folder/image.jpg

Can I use phpMyadmin to search for http://url.com/*.jpg and replace with http://url.com/sub2/folder/*jpg or another method?

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of phpMyAdmin have a find and replace feature which sounds like it might be what you're after.

This can be located by going to the table you wish to search and clicking the `Search` tab, then `Find and Replace`. Put your old URL in the "Find" field and new URL in the "Replace with" field, and click Go to preview the changes. It never hurts to have a backup of your data when making changes.